# I've installed Gecko driver but still getting an error

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I've installed the Gecko driver because i was getting this error : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;"

But after applying the code still i'm getting error for Gecko driver.

Below is my complete code. please let me know what I'm missing.

```
public class Pawan {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\Lalit-pc\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    }

     @Test
     public void test()  {
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Find a Physician")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("searchZip")).sendKeys("32806");   
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mile Radius")).click();
      try{
           Thread.sleep(6000);
          }catch (InterruptedException ie1) {
            ie1.printStackTrace();
          }

      driver.findElement(By.linkText("20")).click(); 
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Specialty")).click();
      try{
           Thread.sleep(6000);
          }catch (InterruptedException ie1) {
            ie1.printStackTrace();
          }
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Anesthesiology")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit'][value='Search Now']")).click();
      String str= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='finderListView']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p")).getText();

      if("Anesthesiology".equals(str))

          System.out.println("Physician Search Successful");
      else
          System.out.println("Physician Search NOT Successful");

      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Browse Locations")).click();
      try{
           Thread.sleep(6000);
          }catch (InterruptedException ie1) {
            ie1.printStackTrace();
          }
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebarMenu']/div[1]/form/div/input")).sendKeys("32806");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebarMenu']/div[1]/form/input")).click();

        try{
               Thread.sleep(6000);
              }catch (InterruptedException ie1) {
                ie1.printStackTrace();
              } 
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebarMenu']/div[2]/section/div/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
      try{
           Thread.sleep(6000);
          }catch (InterruptedException ie1) {
            ie1.printStackTrace();
          }   
      WebElement divElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='overflow-autoScroll']/li[1]/ul/li/a/div[2]/span[3]"));
      String stri = divElement.getText();
      if(stri.contains("32806"))

          System.out.println("Location Search successful");
      else
          System.out.println("Location Search not successful");

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[1]/div[2]/a[3]")).click();   

      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Health Topics")).click();
      try{
           Thread.sleep(6000);
          }catch (InterruptedException ie1) {
            ie1.printStackTrace();
          }

      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Diabetes")).click();
      WebElement divElementtwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h2"));
      String strn = divElementtwo.getText();
              if(strn.contains("Diabetes"))        
          System.out.println("Blog Search successful");
      else
          System.out.println("Blog Search not successful");



      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small setup change requied: (latest firefox browser)

```
public class Pawan {

public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static setup() {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Lalit-pc\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}

// Urs test here
```

Answer (score 2):

To verify gecko driver is compatible with your current firefox & selenium version, do the following:

Keep downloaded gecko driver at **System32** if you are on Windows OS & **/usr/local/bin** if you are on Mac OSX

1. Run the Selenium Standalone server by this command: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar`
2. Open this url in Firefox browser: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
3. Create Session and Select Firefox browser

If browser starts then there is no issue with the compatibility of geckodriver with Firefox & Selenium version.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit uses a different main entry point than the `public static void main(String[] args)` method you've defined there, so if you execute the tests, `System#setProperty` won't be executed.

To add the system property once for all tests in the class, you need to define a `@BeforeClass` method:

```
public class Pawan {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    static void init() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\Lalit-pc\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    }

    //test cases here...
}
```

Now, for development purposes, I recommend setting this variable as a constant accessible by your PATH environment variable (OS dependent) rather than setting it as a system property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define geckodriver in @Test if you do not want @BeforeClass annotation :

```
     @Test
     public void test()  {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\Lalit-pc\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

This will also work:)